# Horizontal bar chart title and symbolic labels adjustments

Tags: pgfplots, titles, labels, bar-chart

I created a horizontal bar chart with some customizations but I run into some problems:

1. How to properly align the symbolic labels?
2. How to center the title to the figure automatically? I guess the title is centered on the bars not the whole figure. (Created a simple macro for designing the bounding box for better visual checking)
3. How to put 3 dots on the legends (\ldots are too wide for my taste)?

Here is an image and a MWE:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[H]
\newcommand{\SSSa}[0]{{Feeling active, vital, alert or wide awake}}
\newcommand{\SSSb}[0]{{Functioning at high levels, but not at peak; able to concentrate}}
\newcommand{\SSSc}[0]{{Awake, but relaxed; responsive but not fully alert}}
\newcommand{\SSSd}[0]{{Somewhat foggy, let down}}
\newcommand{\SSSe}[0]{{Foggy; losing interest in remaining awake; slowed down}}
\newcommand{\SSSf}[0]{{Sleepy, woozy, fighting sleep; prefer to lie down}}
\newcommand{\SSSg}[0]{{No longer fighting sleep, sleep onset soon; having dream-like thoughts}}
\newcommand{\myBoundingBox}[0]{(current bounding box.north east) -- (current bounding box.north west) -- (current bounding box.south west) -- (current bounding box.south east) -- cycle;}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}%[scale=0.7]
\pgfplotsset{plot coordinates/math parser=false}
    \begin{axis}[title  = Degree of Sleepiness,
    %every axis title/.style={below right,at={(0,1)}},
    %title style={at={(1,0)}, anchor=},
    xbar,
    y axis line style = {opacity=0,draw=none},
    axis x line       = none,
    axis y line       = right,
    tickwidth         = 0pt,
    %bar width         = 5pt,
    %enlarge y limits  = 0.2,
    %enlarge x limits  = 0.02,
    enlargelimits=true,
    symbolic y coords = {\SSSa,\SSSb,\SSSc,\SSSd,\SSSe,\SSSf},
    ytick distance=1.1,
    %xmin=0,
    y tick label style={font=\footnotesize,text width=6cm,align=left},
    nodes near coords,
    legend cell align={right},
    legend style={at={(0.2,0.925)}, anchor=north},
    x dir=reverse,
    every node near coord/.append style={shift={(axis direction cs:0.7,0)}}
  ]
  \addplot coordinates{%
  (1,\SSSa)
  (4,\SSSb)
  (8,\SSSc)
  (1,\SSSd)
  (3,\SSSe)
  (0,\SSSf)
  };
  \addplot coordinates{%
  (1,\SSSa)
  (2,\SSSb)
  (8,\SSSc)
  (2,\SSSd)
  (3,\SSSe)
  (1,\SSSf)
  };
  \legend{Before experiment,After experiment}
  \end{axis}
  \draw \myBoundingBox
\end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{Some caption.}
    \label{fig:somelabel}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Aslo got some erros in overleaf:

```
! Package pgfplots Error: Sorry, the input coordinate `0' has not been defined 
with 'symbolic y coords={\SSSa ,\SSSb ,\SSSc ,\SSSd ,\SSSe ,\SSSf }... Maybe it
 has been misspelled? Or did you mean something like [normalized]0?.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You employ a lot of manual shifts. All of those can be avoided with `ytick=data`. The errors also get fixed that way. This addresses the main point, namely the errors, and point 1 of your list. Since I am a fan of one question per question, I stop here, the more though since I thought that point 2 was addressed by Torbjørn T. in a very recent answer, which I upvoted but cannot find any more. Point 3 I do not understand, but I would like to ask you to separate the questions.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.17}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}%[H]
\newcommand{\SSSa}[0]{{Feeling active, vital, alert or wide awake}}
\newcommand{\SSSb}[0]{{Functioning at high levels, but not at peak; able to concentrate}}
\newcommand{\SSSc}[0]{{Awake, but relaxed; responsive but not fully alert}}
\newcommand{\SSSd}[0]{{Somewhat foggy, let down}}
\newcommand{\SSSe}[0]{{Foggy; losing interest in remaining awake; slowed down}}
\newcommand{\SSSf}[0]{{Sleepy, woozy, fighting sleep; prefer to lie down}}
\newcommand{\SSSg}[0]{{No longer fighting sleep, sleep onset soon; having dream-like thoughts}}
\newcommand{\myBoundingBox}[0]{(current bounding box.north east) -- (current bounding box.north west) -- (current bounding box.south west) -- (current bounding box.south east) -- cycle;}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}%[scale=0.7]
%\pgfplotsset{plot coordinates/math parser=false}
    \begin{axis}[title  = Degree of Sleepiness,
    xbar,width=0.55\textwidth,height=0.6\textwidth,
    y axis line style = {opacity=0,draw=none},
    axis x line       = none,
    axis y line       = right,
    tickwidth         = 0pt,
    %bar width         = 5pt,
    %enlarge y limits  = 0.2,
    %enlarge x limits  = 0.02,
    enlargelimits=true,
    symbolic y coords = {\SSSa,\SSSb,\SSSc,\SSSd,\SSSe,\SSSf},
    ytick distance=1.1,
    ytick=data,
    %xmin=0,
    yticklabel style={font=\footnotesize,text width=6cm,align=left},
    %point meta=rawx,   
    nodes near coords,
    nodes near coords style={anchor=east},
    legend cell align={right},
    legend style={at={(0.2,1.02)}, anchor=north},
    x dir=reverse,
    %every node near coord/.append style={shift={(axis direction cs:0.7,0)}}
  ]
  \addplot coordinates{(1,\SSSa)
  (4,\SSSb)
  (8,\SSSc)
  (1,\SSSd)
  (3,\SSSe)
  (0,\SSSf)
  };
  \addplot coordinates{(1,\SSSa)
  (2,\SSSb)
  (8,\SSSc)
  (2,\SSSd)
  (3,\SSSe)
  (1,\SSSf)
  };
  \legend{Before experiment,After experiment}
  \end{axis}
  \draw \myBoundingBox
\end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{Some caption.}
    \label{fig:somelabel}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]